# Views3 date field (filter) treated as string

Tags: views, datetime

I am used to getting int operators(like less then) in views when using date api fields but now I'm getting string operators so I can't filter on dates(like now).
When creating a filter on 'post date' for ex. it works just as usual.
It actually just looks like when you turn off date views.

It's a drupal 7 installation with views3 and the latest date api.

I don't know what went wrong or this is a bug but I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) project there is submodule called "Date Views". Enable this and the operators you're looking for will appear.

[image: Filter criterion]

Comment: In my question I told that it looked like I didn't enable that view, so it's already enabled, that's the problem. I noticed something else, there is no "date tools" in the date config so I guess the date views module is corrupted. I'll try and install it on a new clean installation.